# Creating recycler view item animation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation

I am trying to creating a animation in a recyclerview. The kind of animation that I am looking for is the one which is available in Telegram android app.

When you open a chat in telegram and long press on the message, the recyclerview multi select option comes with checkbox. I am trying to create the same effect.

My current status:
[image]

**ListItemAdapter.kt**

```
    class ListItemAdapter(private val values: List<PlaceholderContent.PlaceholderItem>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ListItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder>() {

    private lateinit var itemClick: OnItemClick
    private var selectedIndex: Int = -1
    private var selectedItems: SparseBooleanArray = SparseBooleanArray()
    private var isActive: Boolean = false

    fun setItemClick(itemClick: OnItemClick) {
        this.itemClick = itemClick
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): ListItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_item,
            parent,
            false
        )
        return ItemViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ListItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.itemView.apply {
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.item_number).text = values[position].id
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.content).text = values[position].content
        }

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            itemClick.onItemClick(values[position], position)
        }

        holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener {
            itemClick.onLongPress(values[position], position)
            true
        }
        toggleIcon(holder, position)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return values.size
    }



    fun toggleIcon(holder: ItemViewHolder, position: Int){
        val checkBox = holder.itemView.findViewById<RadioButton>(R.id.is_selected)
        if(selectedItems.get(position, false)){
            checkBox.isGone = false
            checkBox.isChecked = true
        }
        else{
            checkBox.isGone = true
            checkBox.isChecked = false
        }
        if(isActive) checkBox.isGone = false
        if(selectedIndex == position) selectedIndex = - 1
    }

    fun selectedItemCount() = selectedItems.size()

    fun toggleSelection(position: Int){

        selectedIndex = position
        if (selectedItems.get(position, false)){
            selectedItems.delete(position)
        }else {
            selectedItems.put(position, true)
        }
        notifyItemChanged(position)

        isActive = selectedItems.isNotEmpty()
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun clearSelection(){
        selectedItems.clear()
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    interface OnItemClick {
        fun onItemClick(item: PlaceholderContent.PlaceholderItem, position: Int)
        fun onLongPress(item: PlaceholderContent.PlaceholderItem, position: Int)
    }

    inner class ItemViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
    }

}
```

**fragment_item.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/list_item"
    >
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/is_selected"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />


</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
    adapter = ListItemAdapter(PlaceholderContent.ITEMS)
    val recyclerViewList = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.list)
    recyclerViewList.adapter = adapter
    recyclerViewList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(view.context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
    val myHelper = ItemTouchHelper(myCallback)
    myHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerViewList)

    adapter.setItemClick(object : ListItemAdapter.OnItemClick{
        override fun onItemClick(
            item: PlaceholderContent.PlaceholderItem,
            position: Int
        ) {
            if(adapter.selectedItemCount() > 0)
                toggleSelection(position)
        }

        override fun onLongPress(
            item: PlaceholderContent.PlaceholderItem,
            position: Int
        ) {
            toggleSelection(position)
        }

    })


    return view
}

private fun toggleSelection(position: Int){
    adapter.toggleSelection(position)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add an animated transition, the simplest way is by adding

```
animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

to the individual item root(since that's where you'd like it animated), which in your case would be:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:id="@+id/list_item"
animateLayoutChanges="true" <!-- Around here -->
>
    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

To have it look exactly like in telegram, you'd need a bit of a different design to start with, but that's another issue(and a matter of perseverance in a way :P);

Also if you'd like different types of animations, you'd need to go at it with a different way, you could do it by adding animate to the view: ( alpha goes from 0f to 1f usually((invisible-visible)), and you'd need to change the view visibility paremeter if needed to visible/invisible/gone so that it doesn't register click events on that area, depending on your needs. In any case, this should be trial & error to get your desired behavior)

```
is_selected.animate().alpha(1f).setInterpolator(AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator())
is_selected.visibility = View.VISIBLE
```

You could also [read up a little on available android interpolators](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/animation/Interpolator), since we can't be quite sure whether they will remove some(unlikely)/add new ones.